# Can I use multiple @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I would like to allocate an `Employee` to either a `Reserve` period or `Shift` period.

```
@PlanningSolution
public class RosterSolution implements Solution<HardSoftScore> {

  @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty 
  private List<Shift> shift = new ArrayList<Shift>();

  @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty 
  private List<Reserve> reserve = new ArrayList<Reserve>();
  ....



}
```

Each Shift and Reserve entity has a single @PlanningVariable of

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs={"employees"}, nullable= true)
    private Employee emp;
```

Is it possible to use multiple @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty annotations in a solution? I haven't seen any examples of its usage. The documentation under @PlanningSolution states 'Each planning solution must have **at least 1** PlanningEntityCollectionProperty or PlanningEntityProperty property', but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I'm trying to avoid the single list of planning entities that use type coding, unless I can 'replace type code with state/strategy pattern' (if that is possible).

Comment: Java8 allows multiple annotations of the same type. I'm not sure if they would actually work with OptaPlanner though...

Comment: Thanks. I'm more interested in how the framework operates with multiple @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty annotations. I know it compiles ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The example `CoachShuttleGatheringSolution` and `VehicleRoutingSolution` do it.

It's useful when you have multiple planning entity classes (some of which can be shadow entity classes). But don't go there unless you really need to.